# Difference between FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm a new comer in Android development and still on my first app.
While reading Flags to be send while creating new intend, came across FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

While reading description(I referred http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/ ) what I understood is that in both cases activities on top of called activity are cleared.

can anybody please tell me what are the specific reason to use them and when should I prefer one w.r.t. another one.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reading this.. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html